# How to trigger jQuery .change() from a .prop() function with checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange, prop

**Setup:**

I have 2 checkboxes in the header of a table: Approve and Hide. If the Approve checkbox is clicked it will check all Approve checkboxes in the rows below. Similarly, if the Hide checkbox is clicked it will check all Hide checkboxes in the rows below. There's an Approve/Hide All button that makes an AJAX request. I only want it to make AJAX requests if a checkbox in a row has been changed. When the page loads, some checkboxes will already be selected.

**What is working:**

When a user clicks a checkbox in a row (not the header), `.data('changed', true)` gets added to that single checkbox, and the AJAX request will only send it instead of the information for all checkboxes.

**What is not working:**

When a user clicks the Approve or the Hide checkboxes in the header of the table, it is adding `.data('changed', true)` to ALL Approve or Hide checkboxes in the rows below.

**What I want:**

I only want to add `.data('changed', true)` to the checkboxes that have changed in the below rows. I'm not married to using `.data()`, but it seems the easiest to me.

**Code:**

see [**jsFidde**](https://jsfiddle.net/nxL37arg/).

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="creatives table table-condensed">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="Approve">Approve</label></th>
                <th><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value="Hide">Hide</label></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <form>
                <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_feathr_approved" value="Approve" data-crv_id="{{ crv.id }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_hidden" value="Hide" data-crv_id="{{ crv.id }}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_feathr_approved" value="Approve" data-crv_id="{{ crv.id }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="is_hidden" value="Hide" data-crv_id="{{ crv.id }}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Approve/Hide All"></td>
                <td></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
    $("table.creatives th input[type='checkbox'][value='Approve']").click( function () {
    $("table.creatives td input[value='Approve']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    // this is adding 'changed' to all checkboxes, instead of only the ones that have changed
    // $("table.creatives td input[value='Approve']").data('changed', true);
}) 

$("table.creatives th input[type='checkbox'][value='Hide']").click( function () {
    $("table.creatives td input[value='Hide']").prop('checked', this.checked);
    // $("table.creatives td input[value='Hide']").data('changed', true);
}) 

$("table.creatives td input[type='checkbox']").change( function () {
    $(this).data('changed', true);
})
```

**Misc:**

- I know I need to DRY some of my code, haven't gotten around to it yet though.
- There might be a missing tag or end tag in the HTML from copying/pasting and deleting extraneous stuff. Please ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to do this using `.prop()`, instead I modified the above jQuery.

```
// get all checkboxes in the header of this particular table
$("table.creatives th input[type='checkbox']").click( function () {
    // get all checkboxes in the table cells
    const approveHideArray = $("table.creatives td input[type='checkbox']");
    const approveHideArrayLength = approveHideArray.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < approveHideArrayLength; i++) {
        if (this.value === approveHideArray[i].value) {
            // if the cell checkboxes are different from the header checkbox, add data-changed=true to it
            if (this.checked !== approveHideArray[i].checked) {
                $(approveHideArray[i]).data('changed', true);
            }
            // finally, check the cell checkbox if the header checkbox is checked, or vice versa
            approveHideArray[i].checked = this.checked;
        } // end if
    } // end for
}); // end anonymous function

// this is unchanged from my original post
$("table.creatives td input[type='checkbox']").change( function () {
    $(this).data('changed', true);
}); // end anonymous function
```